# retain grid parameters in jqgrid in reload

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I am using jqGrid for showing the user details in a grid format. I have edit option for these users. After editing the user details I am reloading the grid and that lost all the grid parameter and take me to the first page. I want to be in the same page where I was editing the user. I want all the grid parameter(sortname, sortorder,page etc.) after loading.

Thanks,
Sandy

Comment: See my answer [here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531131/save-state-of-jqgrid-in-localstorage-after-leaving-the-site/6532052#6532052

Answer (score 0):

First you should not reload the complete grid after edit or add or any operation. Load only the grid's data. Use `refreshstate: current` as a grid parameter. Use `reloadAfterSubmit: true`.

You can also study the following link:

[here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3anavigator)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I am trying to use it but after add reloadAfterSubmit: true my grid is not loading. Can u tel me how to use it.