# Retain filter,sort,expanded,page,selection from jqgrid after reload

Tags: javascript, jquery, jqgrid

I need to refresh data from server in jqgrid automatically for 10 minutes interval .
After refresh i need to retail filter,sorting,subgrid expanded, page, selected row(multiple).

I am able to retain all except page and selected row. In this i can able to do either page or selected row only. Cant able to retain both. Only one works for me.

**Code**

```
      jQuery("#tblCompletedPriceList").jqGrid({
            url: $('#tblCompletedPriceList').attr("RequestUrl"),
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: "Get",
            hoverrows: false,
            colNames: CompletedColName,
            colModel: CompletedColModel,
            id: 'PriceListID',
            localReader: { id: 'PriceListID' },
            prmNames: { id: "PriceListID" },
            rowNum: 10,
            hidegrid: false,
            rownumbers: true,
            pager: '#CompletedPriceListGridPager',
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: "Completed Price List Queue",
            height: 'auto',
            scrollOffset: 0,
            gridview: true,
            shrinkToFit: true,
            autoencode: true,
            loadonce: true,
            ignoreCase: true,
            multiselect: true,
            subGrid: true,
            enableClear: true,
            loadComplete: function () {
                UnBlockUI();
                var $this = $(this);
                var selRowIds = jQuery('#tblCompletedPriceList').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrow');
                postfilt = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').filters;
                postsord = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').sord;
                postsort = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').sidx;
                postpage = $this.jqGrid('getGridParam', 'postData').page;
                var selRowIds = jQuery('#tblCompletedPriceList').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'selarrrow');
                if ($this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json") {
                    setTimeout(function () {
                        $this.jqGrid("setGridParam", {
                            datatype: "local",
                            postData: { filters: postfilt, sord: postsord, sidx: postsort },
                            search: true
                        });
                        $this.trigger("reloadGrid", [{ page: postpage }]);
                    }, 15);
                }
                if (expandedids != "") {
                    $("#tblCompletedPriceList").jqGrid('expandSubGridRow', expandedids);
                    expandedids = "";
                }


                if (selRowIds.length < 1) {
                    return false;
                } else {
                    var i, count;
                    for (i = 0, count = selRowIds.length; i < count; i++) {
                        jQuery('#tblCompletedPriceList').jqGrid('setSelection', selRowIds[i], false);
                    }
                }
            },
            beforeRequest: function () {
                $("#tblCompletedPriceList tr:has(.sgexpanded)").each(function () {
                    expandedids = $(this).attr('id');
                });
            }
    });
```

**To reload**

```
window.setTimeout(refreshGrid, 600000);

    function refreshGrid() {
        $('#tblCompletedPriceList').setGridParam({ datatype: 'json' }).trigger("reloadGrid");
        window.setTimeout(refreshGrid, 600000);
    }
```

Comment: would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6531131/save-state-of-jqgrid-in-localstorage-after-leaving-the-site

Comment: The code don't contains `reloadGrid` which will be called in 10 minutes interval. Which options has `reloadGrid` here? You need to save the options like `filters`, `selarrrow` and so on exactly on the place and reapply the options later in the if of `loadComplete` (`$this.jqGrid("getGridParam", "datatype") === "json"`).

Comment: @Oleg: I added the code to refresh

Comment: What I mean: why you don't get the current page number using `var currentPage = $('#tblCompletedPriceList').jqGrid('getGridParam', 'page');` inside of `refreshGrid` function. It's the page number which you want to hold. You can use `[{current: true, page: currentPage}]` option of `reloadGrid` to preserve selected rows and to preserve the page number which you get just before. See [the old answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3808014/315935) for more information.

Comment: @Oleg: Thanks Oleg it works, I have to put all the code in setTimeout of loadComplete. But still i am not able to retain the header checkbox alone.

Comment: @HbV2: You are welcome! I'm not sure that I understand you correctly, but I suppose that you implemented the call of `setSelection` inside of `loadComplete`. You can save additionally the state of `#cb_tblCompletedPriceList` checkbox. It it's selected then you could check it first and only after that compare the saved list of selected rows with the current one. You can call `setSelection` now only for rows which you need *unselect*.